# How to send the push notification to an individual user in iPhone SDK?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, ios4, push-notification

I am creating an iPhone app where in I will require the push notifications.

The query I have is that the users have sent their particular tasks. When their task is over then only that user who has sent that task should get a push notification.

What should be done to send the push notification to the particular individual user?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to specify the device token when sending the message to APNS

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/CommunicatingWIthAPS/CommunicatingWIthAPS.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008194-CH101-SW2

You should save the device token when registering the device for push notifications.

Answer (score 0):

If I am using your application, then I will get device token when registering the device for push notification. For your application, you have to write the code to store the device token in server side. Then, after complete the task, you have to get the device token. Using the device token, you can send the push notification to particular device.

Take a look at following links;

 http://blog.boxedice.com/2009/07/10/how-to-build-an-apple-push-notification-provider-server-tutorial/

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/ProvisioningDevelopment/ProvisioningDevelopment.html