# How to track friend's movement using iPhone?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch, push-notification

There are many apps on Appstore which can show you the location of your friend at that moment if your friend and you have the same app running on iPhone.

I would like to know, how can it be done?

Thanks!

Comment: Check out the answer to this [SO question][1].


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4446576/how-to-send-the-push-notification-to-an-individual-user-in-iphone-sdk

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The app will need to have a server component.  In these types of app, each person's phone connects to the same  web service and reports their respective location.  The server then sends the location of a user's friends (or potentially anybody else using the app, actually...privacy is a big concern with this type of app) back to that user's phone.

So at the very least, the app will need to use Core Location to get the user'S position and NSURLConnection (or some equivalent networking framework) to send that data to a server and to get other user's positions.

Then, of course, there is the server-side part of the program, which receives locations from users, stores them, and sends them to other users.

Answer (score 1):

Basically, have a cloud service. Your location tracking app in iPhone constantly sends back updates to your service. When you know someone is a friend of someone (maybe through Facebook Connect) you can inform them of their location.

I have shown you a very high level picture. There are a lot more finer intricate details here. Please ask what you need...

Comment: thanks for your reply. I would like to know what sort of "handshake" mechanism should I have so that only my friends knows my location and not every one?

Comment: you need to have a website where people who want to use your service login first. this login can be based on facebook connect.this also gives you a list of that persons friends.now this is your handshake, the logi part...